# How to access nested objects of a Json File

Tags: java, object, json

the string I have into "jsonString" is the content of this link: `http://85.18.173.82/cineca/wp5/json/events.json`

Now I want the value "Day" of the second "Event".

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String day = o.getString("XXXXXXXXXX");
System.out.println(day);
```

What does I have to put as argument of o.getString?

Many thanks

Comment: you really should post the json in your question instead of just posting an external link to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);

JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("Events");
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
    System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Event").getString("Day"));
}
```

In this way, you can access, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're constructing your JSONObject is wrong. By using this constructor you're not reading the json from that URL, you're actually using that **string** as a json representation (which it is not).

If you want to first read the json from your URL you'll have to do an HTTP GET request and then construct a JSONObject out of the response.

For more info, take a look at [JSONObject docs](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already done the HTTP request, now I have the content of the file in a string called jsonString.